# Extjs combobox not reflect after store item removal

Tags: extjs

I am new in Extjs and stuck at one point where I want to remove 2 items from the combo store which should reflect in the combobox. Strange thing is that when i put alert message above the following code it refreshes the combobox with those items removed, but not when this alert removes.

```
//alert('test');
var decTypCombo=Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#ddlDecisionType')[0];
decTypCombo.store.remove(decTypCombo.store.getById(16));
decTypCombo.store.remove(decTypCombo.store.getById(17));
decTypCombo.lastQuery=null;
```

Please let me know if I am doing wrong somewhere thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that queryMode is set to 'local'.